# Trying to have add new item to form storing the values of the first before post

Tags: javascript

I have a form which is working and everything. But I want to change it where the user is able to add multiple items. Current I have the form with a select statement and then after selecting they can select the quantity in a text field below the select statement. After doing that I want to give them an option to add another item with the same option and quantity. How would I go about that the form code below:

```
<form method="post">
<p>Team:</p>
<div class="move_val">
    <select name="team">
        <option value="m1">M1</option>
        <option value="m2">M2</option>
        <option value="m3">M3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<p>Item Name / Description:</p>
<div class="move_val">
    <select name="itemName">
        {% for val in users %}
            <option value='{{ val.number }}_{{ val.name }}_{{ val.description }}'>
                {{ val.name }},
                {{ val.description }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<p>Quantity:</p>
<input type="text" class="text" name="quantity" placeholder="3" required="">
<p>Date:</p>
<input type="text" class="text" name="singledate1" placeholder="Click here" required="">
<p>Type:</p>
<div class="move_val">
    <select name="type">
        <option value="Return">Return</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use javascript for this, just copy the last inputs and add them to a wrapper

*Do note you need to change your input names to post multiple value e.g `name="quantity` becomes `name="quantity[]"`*

```js
 $(function() {
 $(document).on('blur', '.elements .element:last-child input[name="quantity[]"]', function() {
             // Force current values into DOM so you can copy them
      $(this).parent().find('input, select').each(function() {
                 $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
             });
             //Duplicate last inputs
             $('.elements').append($(this).parent()[0].outerHTML);
 });
});
```

```css
.elements .element {
  border : 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding : 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<p>Team:</p>
<div class="move_val">
    <select name="team">
        <option value="m1">M1</option>
        <option value="m2">M2</option>
        <option value="m3">M3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<p>Item Name / Description:</p>
<div class="elements">
 <div class="element">
  <div class="move_val">
   <select name="itemName[]">
    {% for val in users %}
     <option value='{{ val.number }}_{{ val.name }}_{{ val.description }}'>
      {{ val.name }},
      {{ val.description }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
   </select>
  </div>
  <p>Quantity:</p>
  <input type="text" class="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="3" required="">  
 </div>
</div>
<p>Date:</p>
<input type="text" class="text" name="singledate1" placeholder="Click here" required="">
<p>Type:</p>
<div class="move_val">
    <select name="type">
        <option value="Return">Return</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Perfect that works. Would it be possible to only make a next field available when I click a button rather than appear each time?